# String tables in Framework

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks, localization

I am developing a cocoa library, which keeps its own string tables for localization.

eg : return NSLocalizedStringFromTable(m_errID, @"ResultMessages", nil );

I added this framework to a cocoa application project.
When I called the Api(with the above code) it didn't work.
When I added this string tables separately to the Application project it worked.

Please help me with a solution, so that the framework Apis use the String table included in the framework.

Regards
Binoy Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSLocalizedString` and friends look for string tables inside `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. If you need to do string lookup in a different bundle, such as `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[MyFrameworkClass class]]`, then you'll need to use one of the variants that also wants an `NSBundle` parameter, such as [`NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle).